# How can I block IP addresses through Windows Firewall with C#

Tags: c#, powershell, command-line, windows-firewall

I have a C# application to block an website. And this is my code:

```
blsite.StartInfo.FileName = ("powershell.exe");
blsite.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
blsite.StartInfo.Arguments = "New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'Block-example_com' -Direction Outbound –LocalPort Any -Protocol Any -Action Block -RemoteAddress 93.184.216.34";
blsite.Start();
blsite.WaitForExit();
```

I have run it, but it didn't work, even though in Windows Defender Firewall showed my rule.

I tried removing that rule, and running the above command directly through powershell got the result that the page was blocked.

Sorry for my poor English

Comment: `-Action Allow`?

Comment: I have changed -Action to Block and the result is still the same